# Updating react state inside react-query onSuccess event causes a memory leak

Tags: javascript, reactjs, memory-leaks, react-state, react-query

I have component called ImageDisplay. And that component uses a custom react hook (useImageUpload)  to upload images to cloudinary using react-query.

The custom hook useImageUpload contains a state which stores the urls of uploaded images in an array. The custom hook returns an object which contains images urls array, a function to upload new images, and isLoading boolean.

The image is being uploaded successfully. But looks like, this react-query snippet is causing memory leak.

```
  onSuccess: ({ data }) => {
    console.log("Image uploaded successfully");
    setImages([...images, data.secure_url]);
  },
```

[image]

How can I update the images array on onSuccess event?

**ImageDisplay.js**

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import "styles/ImageDisplay.scss";
import { Field } from "formik";
import Skeleton from "react-loading-skeleton";
import "react-loading-skeleton/dist/skeleton.css";
import useImageUpload from "utils/useImageUpload";

export default function ImageDisplay() {
  let { images, uploadImage, uploading } = useImageUpload();

  const handleFileChange = (e) => {
    const inputFile = e.target.files[0];
    uploadImage(inputFile);
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(images);
  }, [images]);

  return (
    <>
      <div className="image-display border mb-3 px-3">
        <div className="image-preview text-center">
          <h6>Upload product images to attract customers</h6>
          {/* <Skeleton width={300} height={300} /> */}
        </div>
        <hr />
        <div className="img-choose border p-2 ">
          <div className="options">
            <Skeleton width={100} height={100} />
            <Skeleton width={100} height={100} />
            <Skeleton width={100} height={100} />
            <Skeleton width={100} height={100} />
            <Skeleton width={100} height={100} />
            <Skeleton width={100} height={100} />
          </div>
        </div>
        .
      </div>
      <div className="img-input">
        <Field
          type="file"
          name="productImages"
          id="productImages"
          onChange={handleFileChange}
          accept="image/*"
        />
        <h5>Select product images to upload</h5>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

---

**useImageUpload.js**

```
import axios from "axios";
import { useState } from "react";
import { useMutation } from "react-query";

const useImageUpload = () => {
  const [images, setImages] = useState([]);

  let { isLoading: uploading, mutateAsync: uploadImage } = useMutation(
    async (data) => {
      let formData = new FormData();
      formData.append("file", data);
      formData.append("upload_preset", "uploadPresetHere");
      formData.append("cloud_name", "nameHere");

      return await axios.post(
        "cloudinary_url",
        formData,
        {
          withCredentials: false,
        }
      );
    },
    {
      onSuccess: ({ data }) => {
        console.log("Image uploaded successfully");
        setImages([...images, data.secure_url]);
      },
      onError: (error) => {
        console.log(error.response);
      },
    }
  );

  return { images, uploadImage, uploading };
};

export default useImageUpload;
```

Sorry if I have made any mistake in the question.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71283963/8405310), the callbacks on `useMutation` are always called, even if your component unmounts. However, you can use the additional callback on `.mutate()`, as these callbacks will only be called if the component is still mounted when the mutation finishes. This is documented [here](https://react-query.tanstack.com/guides/mutations#mutation-side-effects).

---

Further, this warning is a red hering, and the warning will be removed in React 18, as documented by the react team in the [React 18 working group](https://github.com/reactwg/react-18/discussions/82). It is stated that calling `setState` in an already unmounted component is not in fact a memory leak and is a totally fine thing to do, while the proposed workaround with a `ref` is actually worse than the original problem (which was forgetting to unsubscribe in useEffects when subscribing to external stores - something that can happen in libraries, but is very unlikely to happen for app developers).

Answer (score 0):

This is a normal behaviour of React Query : if a component performing a mutation using `useMutation` unmounts, the `onSuccess` callback still gets called.

To fix it you have several options, you can :
Keep track of the mounted / unmounted state of the component in a ref :

```
  const mounted = useRef(true)

  useEffect(() => {
    mounted.current = true
    () => mounted.current = false
  })

  let { ... } = useMutation(
    async (data) => {...},
    {
      onSuccess: ({ data }) => {
        if (mounted.current) {
           setImages([...images, data.secure_url]);
        }
      }
    }
  );
```

Not sure it works in all cases though, normally React deletes refs when unmounting a component.

Another solution is to store the images in the React Query cache. After all it's data coming from the server, so it's server state and should reside in the cache :

```
  let { ... } = useMutation(
    async (data) => {...},
    {
      onSuccess: ({ data }) => {
         queryClient.setQueryData('images', prev => [...prev, data])
      }
    }
  );
```